# Passing parameters to compass from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, compass-sass

I'm trying to set custom colors depending on user choice. It will be saved in db but I'm facing a problem. I can't find a way to pass a variable from rails to the scss so compass will take account of it.
Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails 3.1 you may be able to make use of the new asset pipeline and make a `stylesheet.erb.scss` file that is interpreted before being sent to the client.

Keep in mind this will have to be a view, and not a traditional asset, so that it can be sent through a controller and receive parameters for the purposes of rendering.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to rails and though I get a bit of it I don't really know how to do that. I've got compass in 'app/stylesheets' you mean if I turn my stylesheet.scss to stylesheet.erb.scss I'll be able to do that? That's all of it?

Comment: Although I've never done it, you should be able to create a view called `show.css.erb.scss` for some controller and it will render accordingly when called via the usual `/controller/:id.:format` method where you'd specify `css` as the format. This is the only way to get parameters in, as by default stylesheets are rendered the same for everyone.